# DataTables ColVis extension columns visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables jquery plugin in my application.
In my table some columns are not visible. I am trying to use the visibility button to Hide/displayed the columns already displayed. But I do not want hide or displayed columns hidden at the definition of the table,they are only used in jquery for custom filters.
I have used the example in the doc, but it only hide first-child. I want to hide all the columns I had hide in the column definition. I have tried a lot of different syntaxes, but without any success.

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Brtip',
    "scrollX": true,
    "columnDefs": [
        { "targets": [ 11 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 12 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 13 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 14 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 15 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 16 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 17 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 21 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 22 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 23 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 24 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 25 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 26 ], "visible": false},
        { "targets": [ 27 ], "visible": false}
    ],
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            collectionLayout: 'fixed two-column',
            columns: ':not(:first-child)'
        },
        {
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not so complicated, I change the line `columns: ':not(:first-child)'` by `columns:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]`. By this way I just define which columns I want displayed and not wich I want hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the api method `table.visible(INDEX_COL)`, e.: 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()

Comment: This doesn't work because the fields are always present in the list when I click on the visibility button.

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate the columns that you want to be able to hide and show with your button assigning to them a specific class (eg. "dynamicColumn")

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Brtip',
    "scrollX": true,
    "columnDefs": [
        { className: "dynamicColumn", "targets": [ 10]}, //visible column
        { "targets": [ 11 ], "visible": false}, //always hidden column
        [...]
    ],
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'colvis',
        collectionLayout: 'fixed two-column',
        columns: ':not(:first-child)'
    },
    {
        extend: 'copyHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
        }
    }
]
});
```

Then, you can choose to show or hide them using the DataTables `columns().visible()` [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible())

```
table.columns( '.dynamicColumn' ).visible( false ); //hide all dynamic columns
table.columns( '.dynamicColumn' ).visible( true );  //show all dynamic columns
```

Comment: That not what I want to do. The CloVis button is an extension of DataTables button. I think I have to change the "columns: ':not(:first-child)' But I didn't find the correct syntax to put in.